# jQuery FullCalendar - rebinding when the view changes

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery FullCalendar control to bind JSON results from a Web API call. It bind successfully in the month view, and navigating through the months also works fine.

The problem comes when I try to switch to the week view. I have included the code in the "viewRender" section, though I'm afraid I have gone of course somehow. When the 'appendWeek' view is called, I can see that the Web API is hit, and is returning data back from the AJAX call. Using developer tools, I can see the JSON data that I expect, but it's just not binding to the page.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {...},
    eventSources: [
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:61120/api/CalendarApi',
            type: 'GET',
            data: function () {
                return {
                    group: $("#Group").val(),
                    startDate: $("#StartDate").val(),
                    endDate: $("#EndDate").val()
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append(event.EventNumber);
    }
    , viewRender: function (view, element) {
        if (view.name == 'agendaWeek') {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:61120/api/CalendarApi?group=' + $("#Group").val() + '&startDate=' + $("#StartDate").val() + '&endDate=' + $("#EndDate").val(),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (d) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What should I be doing differently to get the week view to display correctly?

Comment: you shouldn't need to do anything in viewRender to refetch events. The calendar will automatically re-query the event sources every time the view changes.

Comment: maybe you should erease prev events for avoid duplicate / triplicate events if the user go back and forth. But if the Id is determined, the fullcalendar may be "smart" enough to handle that

Comment: I had put the code in the "viewRender" event attempting to see if it would do anything different, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue, though it was not a problem with the binding at all. I had changed the styles to make the month view look the way I wanted to, including this line:

```
element.find('.fc-time').hide();
```

This line had the side effect of hiding the entry on the week view. So the date was there, it was just hidden. One of those days...